# Cumulative Transition matrix Markov Chain simulation

Tags: r, algorithm, matrix, random, markov-chains

I have a cumulative transition matrix with probabilities for all the possible states from 1 to 5. Now the algorithm for simulating future states is following: the initial state is selected randomly, and a random value between 0 and 1 is then produced by uniform random number generator.To determine the next state in the Markov process the value of the random number is is compared with the elements of of the *i-*th row of the cumulative transition matrix determined from the preceding state. If the value of the random number is greater than the cumulative probability of the preceding state but less then or equal to the cumulative probability of the succeeding state, the succeeding state is chosen to represent the next state.

```
cum_trans <- matrix(c(0.1686747,0.4337349,0.6265060,0.7289157,1,
                  0.2765957,0.5053191,0.6648936,0.7659574,1,
                  0.2518519,0.4740741,0.6518519,0.7407407,1,
                  0.1911765,0.4705882,0.6617647,0.7941176,1,
                  0.2096774,0.4892473,0.6827957,0.7419355,1
                  ), nrow = 5, ncol = 5, byrow = TRUE)

     [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]      [,5]
[1,] 0.1686747 0.4337349 0.6265060 0.7289157    1
[2,] 0.2765957 0.5053191 0.6648936 0.7659574    1
[3,] 0.2518519 0.4740741 0.6518519 0.7407407    1
[4,] 0.1911765 0.4705882 0.6617647 0.7941176    1
[5,] 0.2096774 0.4892473 0.6827957 0.7419355    1


state<-matrix(NA, nrow=1,ncol=25)
i<-sample(1:5,1)
state[1]<-i
for (k in 2:25){
 rr<-runif(1)
 state[k]<-findInterval(rr,cum_trans[i,])+1
 i<-state[k]
 }
 state
```

So I checked my algorithm it is working but the results are not the same compared to the others. Can someone see the possible issues.

Comment: What is the expected result? If you have a random process, you'll have to define what "similar" means.

Comment: Every state from 1 to 5 represents a certain fixed value  from (1=0, 2=0.5, 3=1,4=1.5,5=2) so if my outcomes are (3,4,2,5) I can calculate the mean of this values and then compare the mean with the original data: the one I calculated the cumulative transition matrix

Comment: Basically I'm trying to reproduce the results from one paper.

Comment: It's unlikely that people will try to read or find some paper, so you should include all the relevant information in your question.

Comment: It is just the algorithm for simulating future states . I'm not sure if I applied the algorithm correctly.